# Same validation for multiple fields

Tags: jquery, validation

I have 3 sets of same fields which are first name and last name of 3 different members. And I am trying to validate the fields on submitting the form. And I am attaching the validation code which is working fine.

My question is, my validation code seems so manual now because I am writing code for each fields. Is there any way to write single line code to validate the same type of text fields with different name attribute?

for example in my ode firstname1, firstname2, firstname3,firstname4, firstname5 , has the same type of validation so I want to write validation code for these fields in short line instead of writing 5 different lines.

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname1: "required",
            firstname2: "required",
            firstname3: "required",
            lastname1: "required",
            lastname2: "required",
            lastname3: "required",

        },        
        messages: {
            firstname1: "Please enter your firstname",
            firstname2: "Please enter your firstname",
            firstname3: "Please enter your firstname",
            lastname1: "Please enter your lastname",
            lastname2: "Please enter your lastname",
            lastname3: "Please enter your lastname",

        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/rw9ns/25/)**

Comment: Will it appear this in real scenario ?

Comment: Please see my answer if it is satisfy your need :)

Answer (score 2):

Plase try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#signupForm").validate();
    $("input[name^=firstname]").each(function() {
        $(this).rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
            required: "Please enter your firstname"
            }
          });
    });
    $("input[name^=lastname]").each(function() {
        $(this).rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
            required: "Please enter your lastname"
            }
          });
    });
});
```

Working fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/rw9ns/34/

Comment: Can u pls check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rw9ns/35/  . This is not working when I combine with my existing code

Comment: Hi Sowmya , thanks for your effort. you are passing wrong id. see http://jsfiddle.net/rw9ns/36/. change your form ID in your jquery `registration` to `signupForm`.

Comment: yes correct. your code is correct But unfortunately it still doesn't work in my page. here is the final fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8JQrj/1/  PLease chk this,  in this those text fields are in loop, you can generate it by clicking on the add person button

Comment: Add validate.js and improve condition for address and zip. i have seen some syntax error. good luck :)